# ElasticSearch: Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

Supposedly in my docs I have a text field which is analyzed. I just get lost in ElasticSearch AggregationAPI. I need support for 2 different cases:

Case A) Result is baskets with counted tokens(terms), descending.

Case B) Result is baskets with counted field texts(whole text), descending. Little complication: I would like to group texts in case insensitive way. Quite a quiz... As far as I know analyzers are a means to create tokens for reverse index. So, it will not help me to group texts in case insensitive way...

Please, give a reference or example,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation and searching uses two different data structures in elastic search

For eg

If i index a field with these values and standard analyzer
data brown ,
    dog    ,
    dogs    ,
    fox    ,
    foxes   ,
    in      ,
    jumped  ,
    lazy    ,
    leap   ,
    over   ,
    quick ,  summer ,the

This is inverted index

```
Term      Doc_1   Doc_2   Doc_3
------------------------------------
brown   |   X   |   X   |
dog     |   X   |       |   X
dogs    |       |   X   |   X
fox     |   X   |       |   X
foxes   |       |   X   |
in      |       |   X   |
jumped  |   X   |       |   X
lazy    |   X   |   X   |
leap    |       |   X   |
over    |   X   |   X   |   X
quick   |   X   |   X   |   X
summer  |       |   X   |
the     |   X   |       |   X
```

Structure used by aggregation

```
Doc      Terms
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Doc_1 | brown, dog, fox, jumped, lazy, over, quick, the
Doc_2 | brown, dogs, foxes, in, lazy, leap, over, quick, summer
Doc_3 | dog, dogs, fox, jumped, over, quick, the
```

- Aggregation also collects the tokens generated from analyzers.

The solution to you problem is

You have to index the same data in two different ways using fields

for eg

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer":"standard",
          "fields": {
            "raw": { 
              "type":  "string",
              "index": "keywordAnalyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will index the same data in two different fields with two different analyzers.
So in first case

- You can aggregate on field1.
- And for your second case you need to build an custom analyzer with tokenizer -> **keyword**, and **lowercasetokenfilter** in token filter and use this **custom analyzer** in **field1.raw**.However it would be better to index field field1.raw as not_analyzed because aggregation on analyzed string field is a memory intensive process and lowercase field value while indexing on code level

Comment: Using multi-fields is something I missed, then I was ready to use multiple my_field for my single logical category. Just because I need the same text to be analyzed by multiple ways by applying different custom analyzers. Now I get that the right way is to use "fields". Thank you!

Comment: Given my previous post, some following questions: 1) If I need text to be aggregated as-is-but-case-insensitive I have 2 different options 1.a) Using custom analyzer of [keyword-tokenizer, lowercase] 1.b) Client-side lowercase in push time. The 2nd options looks me doubtful because I need to get/list original docs anyway.   Regarding your mapping example my questions are: 2.a) What is "index": "keywordAnalyzed". I read that "index" is a boolean parameter. 2.b) Regarding priorities: What "type" should be root and which is supposed to be defined under "fields" ?

Comment: My bad. Instead of index there should be analyzer :keywordTokenized.Second it is completely upto you which should be root and which should be defined under fields. There is no difference what should be root and what should be under fields